# Why pointer in puts() function isn't work in line 4 of the following code? Though line 1 is working

Tags: c, pointers, puts

```
char poem[80]="Amar sonar bangla";
char rpoem[80];
int main()
   {
      char *pA, *pB;
      pA=poem;
      puts(pA);  /*line 1*/
      puts(poem);/*line 2*/
      pB=rpoem;
      while(*pA!='\0')
        {
          *pB++=*pA++ ;   
        }
     *pB='\0';
     puts(rpoem);/*line 3*/
     puts(pB);   /*line 4*/

    return 0;
  }
```

When I run this code, it shows results only for `puts(pA)`, `puts(poem)` and `puts(rpoem)` but no results for `puts(pB)`. I correctly assigned `pB` to pointer `rpoem`.
After coping the string from `poem` to `rpoem` that is `*pA` to `*pB`. But in `puts()` function `pB` isn't show the copied string.  Would someone please tell me the fault?

Comment: `puts(pB);` : `pB` point to `'\0'`

Answer (score 1):

Because at "line 4", 'pB' is pointing at the NUL byte, not at the beginning of the string. You can use a temp pointer in the loop instead of directly modifying 'pB' directly.

Answer (score 0):

Because pB pointer is assigned by null value which replaced to previous value of pB pointer. So line 4 print null value.